# GWT DoubleBox method setValue overrides setText

Tags: gwt

In screen, DoubleBox value needs to be appear as amount with dollar as prefix.

So, I used setText method of DoubleBox so that It will allow be to set string value but its value should be valid numeric value so after using setText, I have used setValue method for setting numeric value.

But, now after using setValue, in screen, only numeric value apears and it neglects behavior of setText. Any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to customize the formatting of the value, then use a `ValueBox<Double>` with a renderer and parser. You can use a `NumberFormatRenderer` based in a `NumberFormat`, but there's no easy way to get a parser, you'd have to implement one yourself.

If you're only interested in displaying a value, then use a `NumberFormatLabel` instead (or possibly cheat by storing the value and return it from the parser, but that sounds hackish)

Comment: Your guidance is helpful to me. I have used ValueBox<Double> and use the constructor provided by this - ValueBox(Element element, Renderer<T> renderer, Parser<T> parser)  for showing double value in desirable format using rendered and use parser for parsing entered value on input element. This constructor is not provided by subclasses like TextBox and DoubleBox. Now I have fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`DoubleBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DoubleBox.html) extends [`ValueBoxBase<Double>`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html), which defines the [`setValue`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setValue(T)) function.
[`setValue`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setValue(T)) internally calls [`setText`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setText(java.lang.String)) after rendering the value using the supplied renderer.
So it will just override your set text after a call to [`setValue`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#setValue(T)).

To be able to customize the text format, you have to supply a custom renderer.
Unfortunately there is only the default constructor of [`DoubleBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DoubleBox.html), which does not allow you to supply a custom renderer:
https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.7.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DoubleBox.java

So you will have to create a class similar to [`DoubleBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DoubleBox.html) with a custom [`DoubleRenderer`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/text/client/DoubleRenderer.html) and probably a custom [`DoubleParser`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/text/client/DoubleParser.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge to me! It helped me to fix problem.